# Send parameters in autoLoad with Ext.Window

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have a Ext.Window and i load TabPanel in it wiht autoLoad from another jsp:

```
var x = new Ext.Window({
  id: 'myWindow', 
  title:'Аттрибуты',
  layout: 'fit',
  autoScroll:false,
  width:600,
  autoLoad : {  
   url : url_servlet+'form.jsp',  
   scripts: true  
  }
})
x.show();
```

Now i want to send parameters in `form.jsp` in this autoLoad. Its possible or i gonna send parameters in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding params in autoLoad config

```
autoLoad : {  
   url     : url_servlet+'form.jsp',  
   scripts : true ,
   params  : {param1:'val1',param2:'val2'} 
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass values from other controls/widgets as params?  I have some combo boxes I have to chain together... I'm trying to prevent the ajax request if the params have no values...